# Sentence extraction from documents using NLP or Deep Learning

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, text-mining, text-extraction

I am looking for references(Papers)/suggestions on how to use deep learning in a text extraction task.

Recently I was given a task to extract important information from documents of similar type, say for example legal merger documents. I have thousands of legal merger documents as inputs. A paralegal would go through the entire document and highlight important points from the document. This is the extracted text.

What I want to do: Given a document(say legal merger document) I want to use DL or NLP to extract the information from the legal document that would be similar to that of the information extracted by paralegal.

I am currently using bag of words model to extract text from the document, calculating sentiment and displaying the sentences with positive or negative sentiments. This yielded very bad results.

Can anyone please provide me with some references and suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: I apologize for posting the question. But I am in very much need of finding a solution to this issue. If you have any suggestions to make I request you to help me @Prune